# use babel features in atmosphere package

Tags: meteor, babeljs, atmosphere.js

I have written myself some utilities and wanna outsource them to a package so I can use them in multiple projects more easily. I would love to write an NPM package instead but the need to access meteor specific variables makes me use atmosphere.

Now I used some es7 like decorators and made them work with the `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` plugin for babel. This works well in the project itself using a `.babelrc` file but I couldn't make it work within the package I'm writing.

I always get the error

```
This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'decorators-legacy, decorators'
```

but I couldn't figure out how I can enable the corresponding babel plugin.

Do I really have to refactor my code or is there a way to enable this plugin? :D

things I have tried:

- create an appropiate `.babelrc` file in package root directory
- trying to hook into `ecmascript`
- trying to use `@babel/core` instead

Comment: Interesting question! You might need to ask the Meteor devs on github issues to get an answer to this one: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues